# getting all possible keyPaths in a dictionary

Tags: objective-c

What is the best / most elegant way to get all possible keyPaths in a nested `NSDictionary` structure?

The structure is not recursive, so dictionary A is not contain a reference to itself, either directly or indirectly.

```
@{ @"root1" : @{ @"level1_a" : @"someValue"
                 @"level1_b" : @"someOtherValue"}

   @"root2" : @{ @"level2_a" : @"someValue"
                 @"level2_b" : @"someOtherValue"}
  }
```

should give `@[@"root1.level1_a", @"root1.level1_b", @"root2.level2_a", @"root2.level2_b"]`

Comment: Is `recursion` to broad of an answer?

Comment: okay, maybe it's a silly question by me then. of course the solution involves either recursion or iteration

Comment: Give an example of the structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know that the structure does not contain loops, you can do it recursively with a simple algorithm:

```
-(NSArray*)getAllKeyPaths:(NSDictionary*)dict {
    NSMutableArray *res = [NSMutableArray array];
    [dict enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
        if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
            for (NSString *suffix in [self getAllKeyPaths:obj]) {
                [res addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", key, suffix]];
            }
        } else {
            [res addObject:key];
        }
    }];
    return res;
}
```